# Create a Sierpinski cube fractal / Menger Sponge using Geometry Nodes

Tags: modeling, workflow, 3d-printing, geometry-nodes

I'm getting ready for Geometry Nodes and want to create fractals starting with a Sierpinski cube fractal / Menger Sponge using *geometry nodes*.

I found a manual way to make it https://youtu.be/WG_q3JBbYFg
[image: pic 1]

I even found a geometry nodes way to make "pseudo fractals" https://youtu.be/gnsUo96tIy0
[image: pic 2]

However creating a Menger sponge using *geometry nodes* still eludes me.

If you want to know why, I plan on 3D printing different cross-sections / slices out to experiment with Magnetic fields and electromagnets. The information can be found here as to why  https://patents.google.com/patent/US20210225574A1/en

Using geometry nodes seems to be the perfect way to quickly create different 3D printable / viewable fractals and their cross-sections at different angles. https://youtu.be/fWsmq9E4YC0?t=231

[image: pic3]

[image: pic4]

More info as to why https://patents.google.com/patent/US10788272B1/en

For more understandable information
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9nHo6O8JLvA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer thanks to Nodevember.  Nodevember 3-4: 4-sided — Menger sponge fractal with geometry nodes

https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/qm8vi0/nodevember_34_4sided_menger_sponge_fractal_with/

[image: pic1]

[image: pic3]

[image: pic2]